# C# write data to a file using a file format and fill string with spaces

Tags: c#, serialization, char, file-format

can someone give me an example what the easiest ans best way would be to create a text file based on a specific format. I have the following example:

```
Field : Pos : Length 
Version : 1 : 2 
Creator : 3 : 4 
Value : 7 : 10 
...
```

One line represents one data row in the file. If a field is less than the length specified in the format, it should be filled with spaces.

So my question is, should I create a class containing char arrays and serialize it. If yes, whats the easiest way to fill some parts with spaces. Or do you have another idea and can give an example how I should do it in C#...

Thanks!

Comment: What if a field is more than the length specified in the format? You have to have an answer to this question before you proceed.

Comment: Hi, this cannot be the case as there cannot be values which are more than the length. They only can be less the length. These are some very specific values/statuscodes predefined.

Comment: If your format is fixed and you don't have a lot of different classes of this sort to serialize, just use string formatting e.g. `textWriter.WriteLine ("{0,2}{1,4}{2,10}...", version, creator, value, ...)`

Comment: Does this fill the remaining chars with spaces if the value is less than the length of the field

Comment: Thanks Anton, thats exactly what I needed. Just tested it and it worked fine for this case, as the format does not contain a lot of fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should look and start from the [StreamWriter documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx). Basically when you created the stream writer you can just append strings to it as you would appent to the console. QUite easy, just remember to use `using` or `Dispose` to correctly close the stream when you finish to write.